# Declare variable in template in Angular 2

Tags: angular, frontend

I want give my users an opportunity to choose which type of input to use to select color: `type='text'` or `type='color'`. So, I wrote this template:

```
 <input [type]="colorInputTypeText ? 'text' : 'color'">
 <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="colorInputTypeText" name="colorInputTypeText">
```

And in `my-component.ts`:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    colorInputTypeText = true;
    ...
}
```

**My question is:** is it allright to declare `colorInputTypeText` as a field of `MyComponent` class, or I should declare it somehow locally in template? If the right answer is "in template", how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this answer was inspired by @Bernardo Pacheco, so please, don't forget to upvote his answer.

Here is the solution:

```
<input [type]="cb.checked ? 'color' : 'text'" id="color" name="color">
<input type="checkbox" name="inputTypeColor" checked #cb [(ngModel)]="cb.checked">
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a problem to declare a field in a class as you did.

But, if you don't want to touch your class, you can do it only in the template:

```
<input [type]="colorInputTypeText ? 'text' : 'color'">

<input type="checkbox" name="colorInputTypeText" #cb (change)="colorInputTypeText = cb.checked">
```

Angular creates a `colorInputTypeText` for you under the hood.

The `colorInputTypeText` is a boolean variable. By default it's `false`, so the the checkbox is unchecked. If you want the default value equals `true`, you have to add the `checked` attribute like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="colorInputTypeText" checked #cb (change)="colorInputTypeText = cb.checked">
```

Personally I prefer this solution because your class don't need to declare an extra property and the logic in the template is easy to understand.

Comment: what is init value for `colorInputTypeText`in this case? can I modify it?

Comment: This doesn't 100% work. Before I first time check/uncheck checkbox, `colorInputTypeText` is `undefined`, so it become initialised and works only after 1st click on checkbox.

Comment: `undefined` in javascript is a falsy value, so the checkbox is unchecked. If you want to initialize with a `true` value you have to add the **checked** attribute in the input field as I said.

Comment: But it isn't set to true until change event occurs. Anyway, you inspired me to improve your answer to make it work. Check it out.